# NFC or BLE to read Mac address of device

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, wifi, nfc, mac-address

Objective: Public WiFi login

Instead of customers connecting to wifi and captive portal to login to WiFi I want the customer to show his phone to a magic ball which will read device MAC address using either NFC or BLE and add that Mac address to the list of allowed devices.

Challenge: reading MAC address using ble or NFC without any apps!

Your input please on how this can be achieved.

Comment: are you expecting us to write it for you?

Comment: Write what? What you talking about bro?

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible without any app. Remember that the Bluetooth Device Address is usually different from the WiFi MAC address.

Comment: Is it possible using app in Android and iOS?